# What would you call shelves failing after being bumped by a forklift?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, material-science

From the [video in this question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/43607/3835), you can see a bunch of stable shelves that are bumped by a forklift. This causes a domino effect, but unlike a regular domino falling over, there is clearly a buckling happening as well.

Did these shelves fail because of compressive force, of shear force?

Comment: The answer to the title question is ‘an industrial accident’

Answer (score 1):

The [domino effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domino_effect) means the supports failed in shear. Two things are obvious:

$1)$ the shear deflection was due to insufficient bracing (no constraint in shear i.e., no bolted connection to the warehouse structure)

and

$2)$ operating near or at maximum load.